# Need to strip chunk of text out of xml file, am not getting anywhere with perl find/replace

Tags: xml, perl, cmd

I need to either remove or comment out the following from around 1.5k files and am having a ton of trouble doing it.  I've tried everything I can think of with perl find/replace, but am not getting anywhere. Any suggestions on approach would be helpful. The tabs above and below it contain properties that change for each xml branch, so I can't use those to find/replace on. I've tried every combination I can think of and am not getting anywhere. When I try to find/replace the string of `*`'s, I get an error that says the argument list is too long. If I try to find/replace on the blank line and 1 `*`, it doesn't pick it up either. A few examples:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\n\*/<!--/g' */*/*.log 
perl -pi -e 's/\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*/<!--/g' */*/*/log
perl -pi -e 's/>\n\*/><!--/'g */*/*.log (this one tries finding the end of the tag above it)

******************************************************

This system is for the use of authorized users only.
Individuals using this computer system without
authority, or in excess of their authority, are
subject to having all of their activities on this
system monitored and recorded by system personnel.

In the course of monitoring individuals improperly
using this system, or in the course of system
maintenance, the activities of authorized users may
also be monitored.

Anyone using this system expressly consents to such
monitoring and is advised that if such monitoring
reveals possible evidence of criminal activity, system
personnel may provide the evidence of such monitoring
to law enforcement officials.

******************************************************
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the flip flop operator?

```
perl -ne 'print unless /^\*+/ ... /^\*+/'
```

See [Range Operators](http://p3rl.org/perlop#Range-Operators) in [perlop](http://p3rl.org/perlop).

Comment: I like this, but I don't think I can find a line, replace it, and flip flop to the next replace value for the next line that matches. This is really cool though, I didn't know it existed. Glad you mentioned it.

Comment: @user797963: What do you mean by "I don't think I can"? This script removes anything between the asterisks. If you want something else, please be more specific.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific. I need to do a find/replace instead of a print. I cannot write the print output to new files either. Otherwise yes, this does work.

Answer (score 0):

Slurps the whole file so you can match across multiple lines:

```
perl -i~ -0777pe's/^\*{54}\n.*?^\*{54}\n//m' file
```